# Gson SerializedName in a Kotlin interface

Tags: kotlin, serialization, interface, gson, data-class

Is there any way to use the gson SerializedName annotation in a Kotlin interface?

```
interface User {
   @SerializedName("user_id")
   val userId: String?
}

data class MainUser(override val userId: String? = null) : User
```

I know the annotation can be in the child class, but that's not what I'm looking for as there are many classes extending that interface.

**Note 1:**
Using abstract or open class as a parent of a data class will solve this, but the new problem would be the overrided equals() method in the parent never get called (mainUser1 == mainUser2 never check the equls() method in abstract or open class User )

Answer (score 2):

I think, that interfaces it's not a good place to have properties (or state). Interfaces very good fits to establish behavior (functions). I'd rather suggest you to use abstract class for your purpose and it will work as you expected.

Comment: Agree, but note the child is a data class. The problem with having abstract or open class for a parent of a Data class is overrided equals() method never been get called.(And interface don't keep the state anyway)

Comment: I can just say I disagree. Properties in an interface _are_ just methods which classes need to implement, and there's no good reason to require `()` after them. See e.g. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/size.html; what would you win by making it a `fun` instead of a `val`?

Comment: Using interface as the parent here is not ideal, but unfortunately this is the only way i found so far that can handle the equals() as well. Have a look at this thread https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/data-classes-should-be-able-to-inherit-from-each-other/4496/11

Comment: and   https://proandroiddev.com/simpler-kotlin-class-hierarchies-using-class-delegation-35464106fed5

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate property getter with `@get` [use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) like this:

```
interface User {
    @get:SerializedName("user_id")
    val userId: String?
}

data class MainUser(override val userId: String? = null) : User
```

Comment: Gson won't parse it this way